# Need Help with UV Unwrap

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]

I'm trying to UV unwrap this object and the main half is perfect but the second half seems to rotate and skew towards the edges so I'm just wondering if my seams are correct?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to square the UV mesh in blender 2.8 so I copied the object into 2.79 and used the UV squares addon and copied it straight back into 2.8